Is there a R function to pair elements from two columns of a data.frame to make a new data.frame
I have several thousand rows like this stored in a object in R. I want to make a new df2 by pairing elements from two columns ($exonStarts and $exonEnds) from the df below
df <- structure(list(bin = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), name = c("XM_011541469.2", 
"XM_017001276.2", "XM_011541467.2", "NM_001276352.2", "NM_001276351.2", 
"XM_011541465.3"), chr = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1"), strand = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), txStart = c(67092164L, 
67092164L, 67092164L, 67092164L, 67092164L, 67092164L), txEnd = c(67109072L, 
67131227L, 67131227L, 67134970L, 67134970L, 67134970L), cdsStart = c(67093004L, 
67093004L, 67093004L, 67093579L, 67093004L, 67093004L), cdsEnd = c(67103382L, 
67127240L, 67127240L, 67127240L, 67127240L, 67127240L), exonCount = c(5L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L), exonStarts = c("67092164,67095234,67096251,67103237,67109028,", 
"67092164,67095234,67096251,67103237,67111576,67115351,67125751,67127165,67131141,", 
"67092164,67095234,67096251,67103237,67111576,67115351,67125751,67127165,67131141,", 
"67092164,67096251,67103237,67111576,67115351,67125751,67127165,67131141,67134929,", 
"67092164,67095234,67096251,67115351,67125751,67127165,67131141,67134929,", 
"67092164,67095234,67096251,67103237,67111576,67115351,67125751,67127165,67134929,"
), exonEnds = c("67093604,67095421,67096321,67103382,67109072,", 
"67093604,67095421,67096321,67103382,67111644,67115464,67125909,67127257,67131227,", 
"67093604,67095421,67096321,67103343,67111644,67115464,67125909,67127257,67131227,", 
"67093604,67096321,67103382,67111644,67115464,67125909,67127257,67131227,67134970,", 
"67093604,67095421,67096321,67115464,67125909,67127257,67131227,67134970,", 
"67093604,67095421,67096321,67103382,67111644,67115464,67125909,67127257,67134970,"
), score = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gene = c("C1orf141", "C1orf141", 
"C1orf141", "C1orf141", "C1orf141", "C1orf141"), cdsStartStat = c("cmpl", 
"cmpl", "cmpl", "cmpl", "cmpl", "cmpl"), cdsEndStat = c("cmpl", 
"cmpl", "cmpl", "cmpl", "cmpl", "cmpl"), exonFrames = c("0,2,1,0,-1,", 
"0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0,-1,", "0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0,-1,", "2,1,0,1,2,0,0,-1,-1,", 
"0,2,1,2,0,0,-1,-1,", "0,2,1,0,1,2,0,0,-1,")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
 

to produce an output like below. The first row of the input df should produce 5 rows of df2 in the format below by paring each element of $exonStart with each element of $exonEnd (the element counts will identical and is present in the column $exonCount).
$chr    $exonStart  $exonEnd
chr1    67092164    67093604
chr1    67095234    67095421
chr1    67096251    67096321
chr1    67103237    67103382
chr1    67109028    67109072

This needs to iterate over all rows of input df and all results combined into df2. So, in total there would be sum(object$exonCount) rows in df2.
I know that there would be some sort of strsplit function in here to split $exonStarts and $exonEnds and then combine them. Maybe an apply function to do this over all rows? I tried something like this first
map2(unlist(strsplit(df$exonStarts[1], ",")), unlist(strsplit(dft$exonEnds[1], ",")), c)
to produced a list of paired elements
[[1]]
[1] "67092164" "67093604"

[[2]]
[1] "67095234" "67095421"

[[3]]
[1] "67096251" "67096321"

[[4]]
[1] "67103237" "67103382"

[[5]]
[1] "67109028" "67109072"

But I do not know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

You could use separate_longer_delim from tidyr
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

select(df, chr, exonStarts, exonEnds) %>%
  separate_longer_delim(c(exonStarts, exonEnds), delim=",")

Which gives (showing first 10 rows only):
    chr exonStarts exonEnds
1  chr1   67092164 67093604
2  chr1   67095234 67095421
3  chr1   67096251 67096321
4  chr1   67103237 67103382
5  chr1   67109028 67109072
6  chr1                    
7  chr1   67092164 67093604
8  chr1   67095234 67095421
9  chr1   67096251 67096321
10 chr1   67103237 67103382

The blank rows are due to the trailing commas in the original columns, which can easily be removed using filter. If you do that, you will see that there are 49 rows remaining, the same as sum(df$exonCount).

As @TarJae mentions, the number of items in each column must be equal, or an error will result. Presumably you are confident that this situation isn't possible.
df$exonEnds[1] <- "67093604,67095421,67096321,67103382,"

select(df, chr, exonStarts, exonEnds) %>%
  separate_longer_delim(c(exonStarts, exonEnds), delim=",")

#Error in `separate_longer_delim()`:
#! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 6 to size 5.
#Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

You'll also get an error using your strsplit approach.

I would recommend using this approach as well! Just make sure that the items are balanced, meaning that each row must have the same number of exonStarts and exonEnds. Any mismatch between the counts of exonStarts and exonEnds in the same row could lead to errors when pairing them.

That's correct, @TarJae. I will update my answer to mention this important fact.

@Edward Thanks for your help with this. The items are indeed balanced, meaning that each row must have the same number of exonStarts and exonEnds. What would be the usage of the filter() to remove the blank rows due to the trailing commas? I tried to remove the training commas first from my df columns before applying your function and it worked. Would filter() be more effecient way?
df$exonStarts <- sub(",$", "", df$exonStarts)
df$exonEnds <- sub(",$", "", df$exonEnds)

Either way works, but I just didn’t want to change your original data. Using ‘filter(exonStarts!=“”)’ may be easier. Cheers!

In base R, we can do
f = \(chr, split, ...) {
  stopifnot(is.character(chr))
  l = strsplit(chr, split, ...)
  # caution, this pads NA's to the end, if shorter than max.
  l = lapply(l, `length<-`, max(lengths(l))) 
  unlist(l, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)
}

(For other applications we need to modify the last line of f().)
Application:
> lapply(df[c("exonStarts", "exonEnds")], f, split = ",") |> 
+   list2DF() |>
+   head()
  exonStarts exonEnds
1   67092164 67093604
2   67095234 67095421
3   67096251 67096321
4   67103237 67103382
5   67109028 67109072
6       <NA>     <NA>

Caution. This approach has the disadvantages of padding NAs to the end of a ","-splitted row of exonStarts or exonEnds respectively if it's not of maximum length. Put differently, it underlies the strong assumption that missing data, if present, is at the ends of each row. As long as you do not carry data containing such information this approach might be appropriate.

Compact:
f = \(chr, split, ...) unlist(lapply(l <- strsplit(chr, split, ...), `length<-`, max(lengths(l))))
list2DF(lapply(df[c("exonStarts", "exonEnds")], f, split = ","))


looking at this base R solution has made me want to dig deeper into that new (as of R-4.1 I think) function definition \(...) paradigm, thnx for hinting in that direction :-D

Note that \(x) is shortcut for function(x). We can read about the dots here https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#fun-dot-dot-dot rbind() is my favorite example. W.r.t. to your question, you might want to pass fixed=TRUE to strsplit.

@Friede Thank you for your answers. As you mentioned, your function did produce NA' of equal dimension as the data that is needed. and I am not sure I understand why are present. Is there a way to not include NA in the output?

Check lengths(strsplit(df$exonStarts, ",")) on the unprocessed data, and you will see. Sure, simply filter. One way to do that would be na.omit(list2DF(lapply(df[c("exonStarts", "exonEnds")], f, split = ","))).

@Friede thanks, that works well.
